# Adding Embedded Youtube video in PHP website gives error in console

Tags: javascript, php, html, embed, content-security-policy

Please Help!

I tried to add an embedded youtube video in my website and failed to load due to below  error. How can I modify the CSP header in one single file(override) without modifying the default CSP. I just want to modify for only this PHP file.

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
</iframe>


Refused to frame 'https://www.youtube.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you publish the CSP.

- If you publish CSP via `header()` PHP function - you can write some logic where to publish which header.
- If you use some plugins for CMS - you restricted by such plugin's facilities.
- If you did it via `.htaccess` file or web config - there is no easy way to override such CSP header. It will be published even on 403/404/502/301/302 pages where it does not need to be.
  Nonetheless you can use [< FilesMatch>](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch) construct (`SpecialFileName.php` is a name of file excluded from common CSP):

`<IfModule mod_headers.c>`
  `<FilesMatch "SpecialFileName\.php$">`
   `Header unset Content-Security-Policy`  # [unset](https://csplite.com/csp31/#CMS_admin) previous CSP header
    `Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; frame-src www.youtube.com;"`
  `</FilesMatch>`
`</IfModule>`

or by use [< If expression> ... < /If>](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if):

```
< IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <If "%{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*/SpecialFileName\.php$">
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; frame-src www.youtube.com;"
  </If>
  <Else>
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';"
  </Else>
< /IfModule>
```

`*` Note: you do not need a space after `<` in `< IfModule` constrict, it's because of SO parser features. Use `<IfModule`.

You can try to do this through mod_rewrite (Rewrite Engine), but this is a complicated way, which is the difficult to debug and manage.

The above is for Apache web server, if you use Nginx - see it docs for similar constructs.